# cudaMalloc is not modifying return pointer when called inside template function

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, nvcc

Following sample problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
__device__ __constant__ float* data;

template<class T> void allocOnly(T* deviceDest, size_t numElem)
{
    cudaError_t errCode = cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceDest, numElem*sizeof(T));
    if(errCode != cudaSuccess) 
        cout << "Got error with code " << errCode << endl;
}

int main()
{
    float* test(0);
    allocOnly<float>(test,10);
    cout << "test = " << test << endl;

    float* test2(0);    
    cudaError_t errCode = cudaMalloc((void**)&test2, 10*sizeof(float));
    if(errCode != cudaSuccess) 
        cout << "Got error with code " << errCode << endl;
    cout << "test2 = " << test2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

compiled with `nvcc test.cu -o testBin`

returns

```
test = 0
test2 = 0x310100
```

Why is test not modified when called through template function, cudaMalloc is supposed to modify it to be a pointer to the newly allocated device memory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer is not being modified because `cudaMalloc` in the function `allocOnly` is allocating memory to the argument `deviceTest` which is local to the function `allocOnly`. You can modify the function `allocOnly` to allocate memory as follows:

```
template<class T> void allocOnly(T** deviceDest, size_t numElem)
{
    cudaError_t errCode = cudaMalloc((void**)deviceDest, numElem*sizeof(T));
    if(errCode != cudaSuccess) 
        cout << "Got error with code " << errCode << endl;
}
```

Inside the main function:

```
int main()
{
    float* test(0);
    allocOnly<float>(&test,10);
    cout << "test = " << test << endl;
    .
    .
    .

}
```